# Theorem on Constants (and Substitution Theorem?)

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

"Let $T'$ be obtained from $T$ by adding new constants $e_1,e_2,...,e_n$ (but no new nonlogical axioms). For every formula $A$ of $T$, and every sequence of constants $e_1,e_2,...,e_n$, $\vdash 
_TA$ iff $\vdash_{T'}A[e_1,e_2,...,e_n]$."

It sounds like the theorem asserts that if an instance of a formula $A$ is provable for certain constants, then it must be provable for in general form, when those constants are replaced by free variables. This doesn't make much intuitive sense to me, and I'm not entirely sure I see how it follows from the substitution theorem, so for clarity's sake, I'd appreciate it if someone could correct me.

Edit: so it is the only if side that confuses me

Comment: You have to write it correctly... The theorem does not assert that "$A$ is provable for certain constants".

Comment: It says that if we can prove in theory $T$ the formula $A$ (with e.g. $x$ free), we can prove in theory $T'$ the formula $A[x/e]$ where the theory $T'$ has an "enlarged" language (the new constant symbol $e$) but no new axioms.

Comment: If there are no new axioms, there is no axiom involving $e$; thus, we have no restriction on it. To prove a formula $A(x)$ with $x$ free amounts sematically to assert that $A$ holds for every object of the domain of every model of $T$. Thus, it holds also for object named $e$, whatever it is.

Comment: @mauro-allegranza First off, thank you for replying to me. I'm alright with that side of the implication, that $A$ being provable implies $A[x/e]$ I understand. That $A[x/e]$ implies $A$ is what seems counterintuitive to me.

Comment: The issue is that an "unspecified" constant (this is the gist of : $e$ new but no new axioms) behaves exactly as a free variable.

Comment: @mauro-allegranza I have no idea how my brain interpreted an unspecified constant as a specified constant, I'd written something down about it when I first encountered the theorem... Ugh, thank you so much!

Comment: The gist is exactly that: if $e$ is totally unspecified, you can interpret it as an object whatever of the domain and thus $A(e)$ will hold of it. But this is the same as asserting $\forall x A(x)$. And what does it mean in Shoenfield's system that a formula is *valid* ? see page 19.

Comment: @mauro-allegranza Yes, that makes perfect sense to me, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Substitution Rule part: once you have the proof of $A[e_1, ..., e_n]$ in $T'$ you may be tempted to prove $A$ in $T$ by simply replacing $e_1, ..., e_n$ by the appropriate $x_1, ..., x_n$ throughout the first proof. However, some of these variables may have been used in that proof, so they may interfere with the ones you've just inserted and ruin everything. The solution is to replace $e_1, ..., e_n$ by some $y_1, ..., y_n$ that weren't used in the proof. Now you have $\vdash_TA[y_1, ..., y_n]$ and by the substitution rule $\vdash_TA[x_1, ..., x_n]$ which is the same as $\vdash_TA$.